# Comparing string against multiple arraylis

Tags: java, collections, arraylist

I want to compare a string against multiple arraylist.

```
 Say String str;
  ArrayList<String> list1;
  ArrayList<String> list2;

   if(list1.contains(str)

   else if(list2.contains(str)

   else if...
```

I want to do it in some another way instead of if else ladder.

Any options?

Comment: what you want to do in if blocks?

Comment: what do you want to do if you found the string in a list? what do you want to do if multiple lists contain the string? where/how is the checking order (`list1->list2->listx..`) defined?

Answer (score 2):

You could have a List of lists :

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> lists = new ArrayList<>();

lists.add(list1);
lists.add(list2);
```

then you can write

```
for (<ArrayList<String> list : lists) {
    if (list.contains(str) {
        // whatever
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

list2 etc elements into one list using addAll() method...like..

```
lists.addAll(list1);
lists.addAll(list2)..
```

now you can iterate your list using for loop  for     list

```
for (String ele: lists) {
    if (ele.equals(str) {
        // do whatever you want
    }
}
```

here you can save the iteration of list of list..

Answer (score 0):

a tricky solution :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ArrayList<String> l1 = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> l2 = new ArrayList<>();
    int i = getIndex("key", l1, l2);
    switch (i) {
    case -1:

        break;
    case 0:

        break;
    case 1:

        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
}

public static int getIndex(String key, ArrayList<String>... arrayLists) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayLists.length; i++) {
        if (arrayLists[i].contains(key))
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: this is good for checking if str exists, but we lost the information found in which list.  but it is fully up to the requirement...

Comment: @Kent yes. for this i asked PO what he/she want to do in if blocks. return type may be ArrayList (then no switch-block) ....